# CSS border-radius for last-child

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have this code:

```
tr:first-child th:last-child    {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
tr:first-child th:first-child   {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
tr:last-child th:last-child {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
tr:last-child th:first-child    {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

I did the same for `<td>` tags as well.

It's supposed to make the table rounded.

Now I have a problem.

I have one table in my website who has hidden `<td>` at the last row, and the user need to click the `<th>` line to show thet `<td>`.

The CSS is assuming I have `<td>` in the last-child of the `<tr>` so it's get rounded. BUT the problem is that it's hidden.

The `<th>` is in the `<tr>` last-child  that the user actually sees, but it isn't get rounded because of that last `<td>` which is hidden and it looks bad.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you can do this with :visible jquery selector. 
https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: you could use nth-child but then you would have to change it when you click on the row that exposes the ;ast row so you're probably better off using a class so you can just remove the class and add it to the bottom row when it gets exposed

Comment: Show more code (HTML, JavaScript). In particular, *how* is the cell hidden?

Comment: The code is a loop with php so it won't help much. But the cell is hidden with `display: none;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nth-last-child](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/). It selects every element of rx+n from the end. (`:nth-last-child(r+n)` or just `:nth-last-child(n)` (assumes r of 0))

```
tr:nth-last-child(2) th:last-child {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **:last-of-type** pseudo class on td. something like `td:last-of-type` should work.